# Using a predated ketubah at a wedding ceremony

Tags: halacha, marriage, time, wedding, ketubah

In Halacha, is it permissible to use written and signed ketubah that predates the actual wedding ceremony?

So basically, the ketubah is written and signed like a day or so earlier than the actual wedding ceremony, but the actual marriage ceremony and “acceptance” of the ketubah happens a bit later.

Is this considered invalid (i.e., does it have to be signed at the ceremony) or not?

Comment: This is a machlokes amongst modern day poskim ,some say it's fine(as long as a kinyan was performed) and others discourage the practice ...

Comment: relevant: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67069/11501

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R David Brofsky, an Israeli dayan, [writes](https://www.etzion.org.il/en/halakha/even-haezer/marriage-and-divorce/laws-wedding-3-customs-and-laws-wedding) the following regarding your question

> One should write the actual date of the wedding on the ketuba. **If the
> ketuba was written and dated before the day of the wedding ceremony,
> and the kinyan and signing of the ketuba happened at a later date, the
> ketuba is deemed a shtar mukdam, which is invalid** (see Gittin 18a;
> Shulchan Arukh, CM 43:7).
>
> **If the ketuba was written and the groom was
> engaged in wedding matters** (*asukin be-oto ha-inyan*) and the kinyan and
> signing of the ketuba did not happen until evening, **some Acharonim
> validate the ketuba *bedieved*** (see Shulchan Arukh, CM 43:16, and
> Ha-Nisu’in Ke-Hilkhata 11:28).

Note the lack of validity of the *ketuba* most often doesn't mean the marriage is invalid, but requires re-doing the *ketuba*.

Of course, anyone facing such an issue should [consult their rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146)
before implementing anything [they learn here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734).